# Verificando múltiplos <select> de mesmo "name", se está vazio com Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tentei de diversas maneiras mas não obtive sucesso, em criar um window.alert(); com return false; se nenhum campo select de name="produto_qtd[]" está selecionado ou se não existe, mas sem êxito, consultei por aqui e nenhuma resposta se adaptou ao que preciso.

Exemplo:

```
<select name="produto_qtd[]" class="form-control">
<option value="">Produto X - Selecione quantidade</option>
<option value="10">10 itens</option>
<option value="20">20 itens</option>
<option value="50">50 itens</option>
</select>


<select name="produto_qtd[]" class="form-control">
<option value="">Produto Y - Selecione quantidade</option>
<option value="10">10 itens</option>
<option value="20">20 itens</option>
<option value="50">50 itens</option>
</select>
```

Ou se o select não existir, também verificar e retornar um window.alert(); e return false; informando "Nenhuma quantidade selecionada", apenas.

Tem caso de que o select relacionado ao produto some devido ao valor declarado do produto ser superior ao do plano contratado, e outros casos o select existe mas não foi selecionado nenhum "value" com valor.

Comment: Mas é um select múltiplo ou múltiplos selects com o mesmo nome? O que exatemente você está tentando fazer?

Comment: É mais de um select, pois foi necessário assim para que o arquivo requisitado pelo .ajax() tratasse o select como array devido a uma necessidade peculiar do projeto.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Faça um filtro nos `select` que tem algum valor.

```js
if ($("select[name='produto_qtd[]']").toArray().filter(function (e) { return $(e).val(); }).length > 0)
    alert('algum selecionado');
else
    alert('nenhum selecionado');
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um map para trazer os valores selecionados.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selecionados;
  $('[name="produto_qtd[]"]').on('change', function() {
     selecionados = $('[name="produto_qtd[]"] :selected')
                       .map(function(){
                            if($(this).val() != '')
                            return $(this).text();
                        }).get();
    console.log(selecionados);
  });
  
  $("#validar").on('click', function(){
      if(selecionados == null)
        alert("Nenhum produto selecionado");
      else{
        alert("Os seguintes produtos foram selecionados: \r\n" + selecionados.toString());
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="produto_qtd[]" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Produto X - Selecione quantidade</option>
  <option value="10">10 itens</option>
  <option value="20">20 itens</option>
  <option value="50">50 itens</option>
</select>


<select name="produto_qtd[]" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Produto Y - Selecione quantidade</option>
  <option value="10">10 itens</option>
  <option value="20">20 itens</option>
  <option value="50">50 itens</option>
</select>
<button id="validar">Verificar</button>
```